# How to clear addproperty value in ant input task

Tags: ant

I have target which in the end call itself on a particular condition but as the values are already set it goes into infinite loop. Is any way to reset the addproperty value.

Answer (score 2):

You could use [ant-contrib](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/index.html)'s [variable](http://ant-contrib.sourceforge.net/tasks/tasks/variable_task.html) task:

```
<var name="your.property" unset="true"/>
<input message="your message to the user" addproperty="your.property"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Ant 1.8 or greater, Ant's built-in `<local>` task provides locally scoped properties:

```
<local name="user.input"/>
<input message="Prompt the user" addproperty="user.input"/>
```

[Local task - Apache Ant's documentation](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/local.html)